# How to pass on value to particular title in django

Tags: python, django, ajax

- I have fetched the value from my table  `MarketingMaestro` whose structure is given below
  `Structure of MarketingMaestro`

```
class MarketingMaestro (models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    total_value = models.IntegerField()
    total_votes = models.IntegerField()
```

- I am able to fetch the value perfectly using for loop which gives the below output in the HTML
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
- So when you click on the `Invest` button from one of the cards, you will be able to invest some amount into that particular project.
- Popup looks like this
  [![enter image description here][2]][2]
- So I am facing two issues here, I am not able to display the particular project name whose invest button is clicked, and after adding the amount and submitting it I am not getting any error but it is not getting saved in the database.
- I am not getting the idea of how should I pass the project name to the ajax code.
- `AJAX code`

```
  $(document).on('submit', '#post-form',function(e){
      // console.log("Amount="+$('input[name="amount"]').val());
      e.preventDefault();
      // getting the value entered
      amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
      console.log("Amount entered by user="+amount);
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'{% url "brand" %}',
          data:{
              name: name,
              emailID: emailID,
              product_title: product_title,
              total_investment : total_investment,
              amount: amount,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
              action: 'post'
          },
          error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
          $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
              " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>");
          console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); 
      }
      });
  });
```

- `HTML` code

```
<div  style="margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;">

  <div class="card-columns" >
    {% for marking in marking_maestro %}
    <div class="card ">
      <img class="card-img-top" src=""  alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" name="title">{{marking.product_title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Random text</p>
        <br>

        <div  class="row" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-modal-lg-1">View more</button>
        &emsp;
        <button onclick="invest({{id}})" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bd-modal-lg-invest">Invest</button>
        &emsp;
      </div>
      <br>
        <label>Total Vote
          <input type="text" id="number" readonly/>
          <br>
        </label>
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Total amount invested {{marking.total_value}}
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Total Votes {{marking.total_votes}}
      <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div  class="row" >
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="incrementValue()" name="uptvote"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>UPVOTE</button>
          &emsp;
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="decrementValue()" name="downvote"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>DOWNVOTE</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade bd-modal-lg-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
    
              <center><h4>Title</h4></center>
              <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'assets/img/about/about.png' %}">
              <br>
              <center><h4>Branding Video</h4></center>
    
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="rembed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UmljXZIypDc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
              <br>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary center" style="width: 200px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    
    
              <br>
    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="bd-modal-lg-invest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Event name - {{id.product_title}} </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                
                <div class="form-group">      
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Project name {{marking.product_title}}   
                    <br>                                              
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Invest amount out of {{context.remaining_amount}}<!-- number 100 should change dynamically after investment (ajax) -->:</label>
                    <form role="form" method="POST" id="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" name="amount">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> <!-- investment saved to database -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You could access it the same way you are accessing it in the for loop

Comment: Hi, please show html code .

Comment: @Swati I have updated the ```HTML``` code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in order to understand your problem I need to see more detailed source code. But anyway I will try to solve it out. As far I understand you don't use **id** in `MarketingMaestro` object. 
At first, when you fetch data from `MarketingMaestro` object send **id** also (it is created automatically by Django). Your object will look like this:

```json
[
   {
      id: 1,
      product_title: "title1",
      total_value: 300,
      total_votes: 20
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      product_title: "title2",
      total_value: 450,
      total_votes: 15
   }
]
```

Now, you are able to pass **id** value to `onclick` event of *invest* button.

```html
<button onclick="invest({{id}})">Invest</button>
```

Your js will look like this:

```js
function invest(id) {
   let clickedObject = myObjectList.filter(o => o == id); //came from django
   //now you're able to access all the fields of object clicked
}
```

And finally, answering your problem in Django, I guess you forget to use `save()` method. Probably, because of this it does not save it on database. In order to say exact solution to your problem put your source code here on server side.

PS: **id** is named as **pk** in Django

Comment: But how do I access the values in the popup menu, how to pass the value to that?

Comment: It depends on, which popup lib do you use. If your library accepts an object as a parameter then just simply pass `clickedObject` to your modal, if not then give an id to modal tag(ex: <div id="myModal> bla bla bla </div>) and replace the text of inside the tag. Something like that: `<div id="myModal><div id="modalTitle"></div></div>`  `$('#modalTitle').text(clickedObject.product_title)`

Comment: Append exact code after `invest` method: `$('#exampleModalLongTitle').text(clickedObject.product_title)`. By that way you can update all fields dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

- **SOLUTION**
- I have just created a new page where I am passing the id value of the particular event to the new page
- HTML part

```
    <a href="{% url 'invest' pk=marking.id %}";><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" >Invest</button></a>
```

- `urls.py`

```
    path('invest/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.invest, name='invest'),
```

- `views.py`

```
    def invest(request, pk):
        event_data = MarketingMaestro.objects.get(pk = pk)
        context = {
                'product_title' : event_data.product_title
                }
        return render(request, 'invest.html', {'context' : context})
```

- It may not be the best out there but it solved my problem.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMjZK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYYto.png